# Changing root directory for Symfony2, .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a Symfony2 application inside a subfolder (api), so i can access a route called 'test' with this url:

localhost/Symfony2-SAP-1/api/web/app_dev.php/test

Id like to modrewrite this to localhost/Symfony2-SAP-1/api/test

If i create a .htaccess inside the api subfolder with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Symfony will catch my 'localhost/Symfony2-SAP-1/api/test' as '/Symfony2-SAP-1/api/test' . This is, i will get the message No route found for "GET /Symfony2-SAP-1/api/test".

If i define a route as:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Symfony2-SAP-1/api/test", name="")
 */
```

well, it will work, but id like to specify just "/test" as the route. How could i make this happen?